# Need help scaling 3 W LED fade circuit with 555

Tags: led, 555

This is my first time doing anything at a component level. I am trying to follow this circuit build, but breadboarding instead of soldering for now: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xyi6eaRnn9c

I am using the following components:

- TI NE555P timer
- NTE 2N2222A NPN transistor
- Capacitor is 1000 μF
- Resistor at 18b to 27+ is 100 Ω
- Resistor at 17c to 17h is 1 kΩ
- Resistor at 13b to 15b is 10 kΩ

I am able to get the circuit to work as expected using a single, typical LED light. However, the end goal is to power/fade a 3 W LED automotive brake light (I am trying to build a blinking light for a marching band prop; it needs to be bright enough to see during daylight). You can see the circuit as wired here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8LmR.jpg

When I power the 3 W brake light directly using 9 V, it is very bright. As soon as I connect it to the circuit, nothing happens.

I also tried with an 11 V, 4000 mAh drone battery. Again, the normal LED worked, but not the brake light LED.

Any suggestions for changes to the circuit? How can I get enough current to the 3 W LED?

Something brought to my attention is that the 3 W brake light bulb is drawing 0.22 A at 12 V while the 555 timer has a max output less than that. It seems like that is my bottleneck, but like I said, this is my first attempt at building any circuit and I am unsure what adjustments to make. I did find this resource, but I don't know what to do with it: http://www.555-timer-circuits.com/increasing-output-current.html

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi! Indeed you cannot drive a powerful LED with the 555 directly. But your 2N2222 transistor should take care of that. People will appreciate if you add a schematic diagram of your circuit rather than just a photograph of the breadboard. It will greatly improve your odds of receiving helpful answers.

Comment: For schematics there is an integrated editor you can use.

Comment: 3 W Could be 1 or more LEDs with resistors, Which is it?  share a link to LED or photo

Comment: @polwel- I will look into learning how to use CircuitLab and keep that in mind for the future!

Comment: @tony-stewart-ee75 In regards to the 3w LED, it is this auto brake light bulb- [link](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01MY4T4BU/)

Comment: Ok then the LED is 3W but the load is 9V min so 1/3A constant current over voltage range if 3W was accurate. But you measured 0.22A so that's only 2W @ 9V and I presume they regulated to constant current.

Comment: Are you trying to get one per player because they won't all be in sync. Also do you want 1/4 time or 4/4 time or wrong time. I suspect you can do better with the 11V battery . The LED draws 0.22 A so it appears like a 50 ohm load.11V / 0.22A. Using a collector from a PN2222A to drive the -ve side low to  grounded emitter  with the 555 using a 500 Ohm to 1k ohm resistor to drive the base.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 the measurement on the LED is 3w, .22A @ 12V. Fundamentally I am trying to run the circuit / light with an 11v battery because it is what I have on hand. I am not trying to sync the blinking to the band... just get a subtle fade in / out like a typical radio tower antenna.

Comment: define subtle fade. most towers here blink slow or slower  . ? rate, rising ramp, falling ramp,  Sawtooth? Triangle ? Sine wave? Pulse?  . cycle time? tolerance?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Like this fade blink- https://youtu.be/Xyi6eaRnn9c?t=215 Perhaps a little longer cycle... it does not need to be a tight / exact tolerance. This is just background visuals. The circuit will go inside of a 3d printed cap on top of the antenna here- https://imgur.com/a/cBy9sHZ

Comment: You will have to test the Red Brake LED with a variable voltage below 9V to see when it goes dim. My guess is <8V

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 You guessed correctly... I used from (5) AA batteries in series to measure 8V and it powered the light but only dimly. (4) AA batteries in series (measuring 6.4V) did not power the light at all.

Comment: @polwel which integrated editor are you referring to? I have tried a bunch online with varying (bad) experience or gated behind a paywall... EDIT- never mind I see that when asking new questions, CircuitLab is integrated

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Following this voltage discussion... I monitored the voltage at the LED part of the circuit and its only peaking at 3V

Comment: Where is the rest of the voltage dropping from ? a power resistor or a regulator? We can only guess what's inside

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I created a diagram of the circuit here... the one on the right is adding the TIP31 as suggested below- https://imgur.com/a/ypsngcj

Comment: none of this is certain without knowing the current all voltages in order to dim properly

Answer (score 2):

The circuit is using a BJT as an emitter-follower fed from the electrolytic capacitor voltage. The timing resistor is 10K. With a 220mA load you'll need a current gain of minimum 1000 (preferably more) or the BJT base will load the capacitor excessively and the oscillator will stop. A BC547 does not  have that much gain, and if it did it would likely overheat and fail.

One option is to add a TIP31 power transistor as so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9RrIp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You might also be able to replace both with a logic-level MOSFET such as IRLZ44 connected as a source follower.

Comment: Thanks for posting this! I have a collection of new transistors on the way and will give this a try this weekend!

Comment: First.. I tried to draw the circuit... I hope I got it correct- https://imgur.com/a/ypsngcj

Comment: Second.. I added the TIP31. It runs with the normal LED, but still not running with the 3w LED (.22A @ 12V). Adding the TIP31 also is not fading out as expected... 30s video- https://imgur.com/a/8wyc9mL

Comment: Are you sure you got the TIP31 pinout correct? It's B-C-E from the front.

Comment: Yes I have the emitter of the 2n2222a going to the base of the TIP31. The collector is connected to the positive of the battery. The emitter is going to the positive of the 3w LED. This is my first thing I've ever tried... so I'm certainly open to the idea I have something wired wrong. I did tear everything down and rebuilt it

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to get this working properly... so I moved on to an arduino nano approach.